# Restar el numero mayor de una lista JAVA

Tags: java, bucle-for

Tengo la siguiente inquietud con el siguiente código, necesito hacer que haga la resta por el número primo menor al ingresado, en este momento hace la resta pero por el primer numero primo que encuentra en la lista.

Muchas gracias aquí dejo el código que tengo.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import javax.swing.*;


public class calculo {
    int n = 0;

    public List<Integer> listaPrimos(){  
        List <Integer> listaPrimos = new ArrayList();

        for (int i=2;i<n;i++){
            if(primo(i)){
                listaPrimos.add(i); 
            }
       }
       return listaPrimos;
    }

    public boolean primo(int i){
        int contador = 0;

        for(int I = 1; I <= i; I++)
        {
            if((i % I) == 0)
            {
                contador++;
           }
        }

        if(contador <= 2)
        {
            return true;
        }else
        {
            return false;
        }
    }

    public void logica (){

        if(primo(n)){
            System.out.println("El numero ingresado es primo: "+n);
            int salida=0;
            listaPrimos();
            List <Integer> listaPrimos = listaPrimos(); 

            for (Integer nPm : listaPrimos){

                if(n>nPm){
                    salida=(n-nPm)/2;
                    System.out.println("["+n+"] - ["+nPm+"] / ["+2+"] ="+salida);
                }
                break;

         }
         else{
             System.out.println("El numero ingresado no es primo: "+n);
         }

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        calculo calculo1 = new calculo();
        calculo1.n = 353;
        calculo1.listaPrimos();
        calculo1.logica();

   }
}
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Osea dado un numero N, buscar el número primo P más grande que sea menor que N y hacer la resta N - P ?

Answer (score 0):

El problema estaba aquí:

```
    public void logica (){

    if(primo(n)){
        System.out.println("El numero ingresado es primo: "+n);
        int salida=0;
        listaPrimos();
        List <Integer> listaPrimos = listaPrimos(); 
        for (Integer nPm = listaPrimos.get(listaPrimos.size()-1);primo(nPm);){
            if(n>nPm){
                salida=(n-nPm)/2;
                System.out.println("["+n+"] - ["+nPm+"] / ["+2+"] ="+salida);
            }
            break;

     }
    }
     else{
         System.out.println("El numero ingresado no es primo: "+n);
     }

}
```

**Deberías haber igualado para nPm el penúltimo elemento de tu lista de primos.**

El problema era que estabas cogiendo el menor primo de la lista,
lo que se soluciona con:

```
 for (Integer nPm = listaPrimos.get(listaPrimos.size()-1);primo(nPm);){
```

Échale un vistazo a los diferentes métodos de las listas en java.